# Web page not working correctly using electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to simply load some pages with electron, one of this is the tiktok website, when i load this page i cannot visit mine and other users profiles and i'm wondering why

## @CODE

My electron application is really basic

```
function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
   win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 750,
    frame: false,

    icon: 'icons/png/icon.png',
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  });
  win.loadURL("https://www.tiktok.com");
  win.setMenuBarVisibility(false);

  win.setResizable(true);
  win.on('closed', () => {
    app.quit();
  });

}

app.on('ready', createWindow);
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if(process.platform !== 'darwin'){
    app.quit();
  }
});
```

It just create a window and as url i setted now the tiktok website.

## @ISSUE

when i try to load that pages insteat the profiles datas the request returns *Page not aviable*

[image]

I also tried with different window sizes and by adding different user agents.

In the window console that tries to load the profile this error appears:

```
profile:66 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException
(anonymous) @ profile:66
load (async)
(anonymous) @ profile:65
```

Related to this tiktok page script

```
// Check that service workers are supported
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
 // Use the window load event to keep the page load performant
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js');
    });
 }
```

( But it gives the same error if i go in other pages of the website that are correctly load for example in the trending page, instead the `@ profile` it says `@ trending` and so on for all the pages So i think that's irrelevand but maybe i'm wrong)

In the main console no error are raised.

I saw that the problem could be the `nodeintegration` preference but if i set it to false the app doesn't work anyway

```
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false
    },
```

Anyone has any advice or know why it doesn't load this page?

I tested to load on other browsers for check if that was my pc/internet problem but it works.

Comment: Is there any error message? Or does the page just not load?

Comment: This is not related to nodeIntegration

Comment: Can you share the browser console output?